# what is the best practice to call a function in html using angular2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i am calling a function using html binding expression(template interpolation) in angular2 while doing this the console statements are printing continuously. 
Is this is the only way to do or any different ways to call a function in html. i have use the similar syntax in angularjs-v1 have no issues! any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

### html

```
 <button ion-button (click)="addProduct(totalSingleItem,getTotalItemPrice(totalSingleItem))" >addProduct
          <span>: {{getTotalItemPrice(singleItem) * singleItem.quantity}}</span>
      </button>
```

### ts

```
private getTotalItemPrice(ITEM) {
return totalPrice; //(eg: 75$)

}
```

Comment: It's best to not call a function from HTML, calculate the result in advance, assign it to a field and bind to that field. Binding to functions is prone to hurt performance of your application, because Angulars change detection calls these functions every time it runs change detection.

Comment: I would reccomend using a custom pipe. `{{singleItem | getTotalItemPrice: singleItem.quantity}}`. The logic would obviously have to be inside the pipe declaration.

Comment: yes as per your use case this is the only way bu as @GünterZöchbauer said this is not good practice due to change detection strategy. so avoid it as much as you can

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom pipe for that purpose.

TS:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'getTotalItemPrice'})
export class GetTotalItemPrice implements PipeTransform {
  transform(item: any, quantity: number): number {
    let totalPrice: number = 0;
    // your logic
    return totalPrice;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
{{singleItem | getTotalItemPrice: singleItem.quantity}}
```

Comment: i too have the same problem, but in my requirement if i want to change the quantity of item from `1`  to `2` then the pipe is not calling when quantity changed, so the price is showing for only `1` item, could you please help me to get out of this @D. Simon

Comment: @Midhunsai open a new question with a code example.